# How to flatten a tree with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, treeview, typescript-typings

I have this TypeScript code:

```js
function flattenTree <T, K extends keyof T>(tree: T, key: K): T[] {
  const flattedTree = {
    ...tree,
  };
  delete flattedTree[key];

  if (Array.isArray(tree[key]) && (tree[key] as any as T[]).length > 0) {
    return [flattedTree].concat(
      (tree[key] as any as T[]).map(child => flattenTree(child, key))
        .reduce((pre, next) => pre.concat(next)),
    );
  }

  return [flattedTree];
}
```

Input:

```
interface ShopTree {
  shopId: string;
  name: string;
  nodeType: string;
  children: ShopTree[];
}
const testObj: ShopTree = {
  shopId: '123',
  name: 'KFC(root)',
  nodeType: 'ROOT‘,
  children: [
    {
      shopId: '23',
      name: 'KFC(middle)',
      nodeType: 'MIDDLE',
      children: [{
        shopId: '45',
        name: 'KFC(leafA)',
        nodeType: 'LEAF’，
      }]
    },
    {
      shopId: '234',
      name: 'KFC(leafB)',
      nodeType: 'LEAF’，
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

```js
console.log('result', flattenTree(testObj))

[
  {
    shopId: '123',
    name: 'KFC(root)',
    nodeType: 'ROOT‘,
  },
  {
    shopId: '23',
    name: 'KFC(middle)',
    nodeType: 'MIDDLE',
  },
  {
    shopId: '45',
    name: 'KFC(leafA)',
    nodeType: 'LEAF’，
  }
  ....
]
```

Could someone give me an idea of how to write the right types for the function?

While the output has no property value of `children` and I don't want to use `as any as xxx` in the code.

Could someone give me an idea of how to write the right types for the function?

While the output has no property value of `children` and I don't want to use `as any as xxx` in the code.

Comment: Could you show an example how you want to use it? With that I mean, what does the tree look like? Is it literally a single type, or do you want it to work on all recursive data structures?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your tree is structured, it's a little difficult to provide any more precise help. Here's an example of how the type might look:

```js
const flattenTree = <T>(tree: INode<T> | null): T[] => tree === null
    ? []
    : [tree.value, ...flattenTree(tree.left), ...flattenTree(tree.right)]
```

A flattened tree of `<T>` returns `T[]`

---

Here's a full example of how that would flatten a tree:

```js
interface INode<T> {
    left: INode<T> | null;
    right: INode<T> | null;
    value: T;
}

const flattenTree = <T>(tree: INode<T> | null): T[] => tree === null
    ? []
    : [tree.value, ...flattenTree(tree.left), ...flattenTree(tree.right)]

const testTree: INode<number> = {
    left: {
        left: null,
        right: {
            left: null,
            right: {
                left: null,
                right: null,
                value: 7,
            },
            value: 5,
        },
        value: 3,
    },
    right: {
        right: {
            left: {
                left: null,
                right: null,
                value: 0,
            },
            right: null,
            value: 9,
        },
        left: {
            right: null,
            left: null,
            value: 1,
        },
        value: 10,
    },
    value: 2,
};

const result = flattenTree(testTree);
console.log(result); 
/* gives:
0: 2
1: 3
2: 5
3: 7
4: 10
5: 1
6: 9
7: 0
*/
```

[Typescript playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkD2ATCAeAFQD5kBvAKGSuQBsIYwAuNLXQkgH2RAFcaaA3JWpRgAcwAWTFjnzFkXXvyHVkANzg0eEZgSEBfcuQSYQAZzDIYNOGEggCUCCgC8ydgAowTnTLbzFPhoASl0AbQBdZBcSb2dolzclGmEqAH5kSNTkZjC4iAA6DS0IABpkAsrrW3tHZy8fAroGYPLKguq7CAcfBucC0UkwYIijE3NLSAs63wxZPF4AWwAjaBI3ClVm6U3Vam3mZNLs1UGpZl29vYPuIOOrq7Odk4et%20mkjl9eqJ8O7r%20%20xW0zAA7PdvlR9OCIUDfABWaF7KEA2HMADMiORp3E5zIAN%20eIhVBulyJxPef34iLJBM%20ZNUqOQAAZqQ8sUTaf8yYyAJysyH82gUwkcnEfLlEm50omMgCMgvZVzlLOyivUmmByAATMd9EJjKYLMgnGY%20JY3J1ar0pmAZsEhOMzJg6E1MGIPCazfbyEA)